# Integral that makes square root of $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

My question is regarding a integral that´s giving me a huge headache.

I want to show $$\int_{0}^{\infty}y^2e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

I'm studying for an exam. I'm suppose to find the integral of $(x^2/c^2)\, e^{-x^2/(2c^2)}$ between $0$ and $\infty$.

So first i substituted $x/c = y$ which makes the integral simpler. Then I'm stuck, I'm guessing that the equation that appears when substituting like this, is well know(a standard integral used a lot) which is equal to integral of pi/2.

Comment: You may integrate by parts twice and use the gaussian result. Another way is to differentiate with respect to $a$ the identity $\int_0^\infty e^{-ay^2}dy=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{a}}$.

Comment: Also, you can set  $\frac{y^2}{2}=u$ and apply gamma function

Comment: Or, if familiar with/allowed to use standard results in probability, you have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy = \mathbb{E}[X^2]=\operatorname{Var} X=1$ where $X\sim\mathcal{G}(0,1)$ is a standard Gaussian. Please, let us know what you have tried, and what you can assume known. Without that, we cannot really help you.

Comment: Integrate by parts once $u=y$, $dv$ the rest reduces it to a familiar integral.

Comment: duplicate...duplicate...duplicaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaate!

Comment: I have incorporated the non-answer from below.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

note that:
$$
\int x^2e^{-x^2}dx=\int x\cdot\left(xe^{-x^2}\right)dx=\int x d\left( -\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2}\right)
$$

and integrate by parts using the fact that
$$
\int e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\mbox{erf}(x)+C
$$
where $\mbox{erf}(x)$  is the [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: It's unclear that the OP can use that fact, though... Literally, at that point we know nothing about what (s)he's allowed to use and what results are alright to take as "standard."

Comment: Yes.we can substitute the Error function with the fact that $\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^2)dx=\sqrt{\pi}/2$ ( if this is known by OP).

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon one of the earlier comments, you can use differentiation under the integral sign. Notice

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}y^2{e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}}dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}-2\lim_{t \rightarrow 1} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}{e^{\frac{-ty^2}{2}}}dy=-2\lim_{t \rightarrow 1} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{\frac{-ty^2}{2}}}dy.$$

To solve for $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{\frac{-ty^2}{2}}}dy,$$ you can square the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{\frac{-t(x^2+y^2)}{2}}}dxdy,$$
and convert to polar coordinates:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}r{e^{\frac{-tr^2}{2}}}drd\theta=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{t}d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2t}.$$

This means $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{\frac{-ty^2}{2}}}dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2t}}.$$

Now compute $$-2\lim_{t \rightarrow 1} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2t}}=\frac{{}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$ which is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=e^{-y^2/2}$, then $\mathrm{d}u=-ye^{-y^2/2}$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty y^2e^{-y^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}y
&=-\int_0^\infty y\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{1}\\
&=\int_0^\infty u\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{2}\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{3}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $u=e^{-y^2/2}$
$(2)$: integration by parts
$(3)$: undo the substitution

Now if we have $A=\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}y$, we can square to get
$$
\begin{align}
A^2
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{4}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{5}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-r^2/2}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\tag{6}\\
&=\frac\pi2\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/2}r\,\mathrm{d}r\tag{7}\\
&=\frac\pi2\left[-e^{-r^2/2}\right]_0^\infty\tag{8}\\
&=\frac\pi2\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: square the integral
$(5)$: combine the two integrals (since they are absolutely convergent)
$(6)$: convert to polar coordinates
$(7)$: integrate in $\theta$
$(8)$: integrate in $r$
$(9)$: evaluate

Combining the two results we get above yields
$$
\int_0^\infty y^2e^{-y^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}y=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\tag{10}
$$

Comment: hey rob, you can also go directly into polar coordinates without integration by parts

Comment: @tired: I imagine so. I don't see how immediately. Do you have an example?

Comment: $$
I^2=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}dxdyx^2y^2e^{-x^2/2-y^2/2}=8\int_0^{\infty} drr^5e^{-r^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}d\phi\sin^2(\phi)\cos^2(\phi)=8\cdot1\cdot\frac{\pi}{16}\\
\rightarrow I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: Of course, doh! Thanks. I would then have felt compelled to evaluate the trig integral, but that's just me.